# custom object Lookup relation should be given to OpportunitylineItem or opportunity product

Tags: relationships, opportunity-lineitem

I have created a custom object as OpportunitylineItem and wanted to give a lookup relation with standard opportunityline item .So now i should create with the opportunity product or standard opportunityline item.

How should i populate the Schedule related list field Date with other fields

Comment: Please clarify your question. What is the Schedule related list, how is it related to your custom object, what do you want to populate the fields with, etc. You seem to be jumping around and missing key pieces of information

Comment: as @sfdcfox told you in an earlier question, Opportunity Product is the user label for the SObject `OpportunityLineItem`. Creating a custom object called `OpportunityLineItem__c` will only lead to confusion

Comment: @Eric :1) I have a custom object named as OpportunityLineItem .Its should have a lookup relation ship created standard opportunityline item.So now i should create with the opportunity product or standard opportunityline item.2)In the Standard OpportunityLineItem i could see Schedule (OpportunityLineItemSchedule)as a related list,with their date field,quantity etc.Now i would like to Dynamically populate the value of pricing request instead of date column.How to achieve this.Any help is very much appreciated.